# Are there any other language models besides GPT-3 that can be used to create chatbots with a specific identity and environment?

Tags: open-ai, gpt-3, dialogue-systems

I've recently been looking into language models but ran into a small question out of curiosity. For some language models like GPT-3, it is possible to generate dialogue, with the model basing its answers on the initial input (which can be anything). This makes it possible to make a "bot" which a user can chat with, that identifies itself a certain way (ex. gender and job), has certain mannerisms (ex. polite or angry) and knows things about a custom world (ex. The bot is a cashier in a certain store, located in a certain city).

Newer and better models for open-domain dialogue such as Facebook Blenderbot do not seem to have this possibility, it chats with the user but does not have to setup a certain context. Are there any other language models that can do this, and might perform better than GPT-3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look at Chirpy Cardinal from Stanford. It doesn't provide mannerisms out of the box but the response generators can be configured to give each instance its own character.

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/chirpycardinal/